# EF Core 3.1 - The LINQ expression could not be translated (left joins with group by)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

```
var query = await (from funnel in _readerBaseQuery
                        join lead in _readerContext.Leads on funnel.Id equals lead.SalesFunnelId into leadFunnelGroup
                        from leadFunnel in leadFunnelGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join leadProduct in _readerContext.LeadProducts on leadFunnel.Id equals leadProduct.LeadId into leadProductGroup
                        from product in leadProductGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        group new { LeadId = leadFunnel.Id, TotalFirst = product.TotalFirst } by leadFunnel.SalesFunnelStageId into newGroup
                        select new { 
                            SalesFunnelStageId = (long)newGroup.Key, 
                            LeadsCount = newGroup.Select(x => x.LeadId).Count(),
                            LeadsValue = newGroup.Select(x => x.TotalFirst).Sum()
                        })
                        .ToListAsync();
```

I'm trying to a simple group by operation in my API/repository layer using EF Core and LINQ and it throws the error like below:

```
The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (l.SalesFunnelStageId), 
ElementSelector:new { 
    LeadId = (ProjectionBindingExpression: LeadId), 
    TotalFirst = (ProjectionBindingExpression: TotalFirst)
 }
)
.Select(x => x.LeadId)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

The SQL query is like below which I tried in MySQL and it works fine [Query executed in MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3oIZ.png)

```
 select l.SalesFunnelStageId, count(distinct l.Id) as LeadsCount, sum(lp.TotalFirst) as LeadsTotal
    from salesfunnels f
    left join leads l on l.SalesFunnelId = f.Id
    left join leadproducts lp on lp.LeadId = l.id
    group by l.SalesFunnelStageId
```

Is there something wrong with the way the LINQ query or how the group by is written in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change grouping projection to be translatable. `Select` with grouped items is not supported. `Count` by not nullable filed also not supported till EF Core 5.x and can be emulated by `Sum`.

```cs
var query =
    from funnel in _readerBaseQuery
    join lead in _readerContext.Leads on funnel.Id equals lead.SalesFunnelId into leadFunnelGroup
    from leadFunnel in leadFunnelGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join leadProduct in _readerContext.LeadProducts on leadFunnel.Id equals leadProduct.LeadId into leadProductGroup
    from product in leadProductGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new { leadFunnel, product } by leadFunnel.SalesFunnelStageId into newGroup
    select new { 
        SalesFunnelStageId = (long)newGroup.Key, 
        LeadsCount = newGroup.Sum(x => (int?)x.leadFunnel.LeadId != null : 1 : 0),
        LeadsValue = newGroup.Sum(x => x.product.TotalFirst)
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! your suggestion and solution worked. I updated the group by projections to include the whole entities instead of the Ids and fields and it worked like a charm!
But is there any way to use Distinct() as well, cause the counts are including duplicate Ids for the LeadsCount now.

Comment: It is supported only in EF Core 5.x

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks for all your help!